# SciKit-Learn Label Encoder resulting in error 'argument must be a string or number'

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection, one-hot-encoding

I'm a bit confused - creating an ML model here.

I'm at the step where I'm trying to take categorical features from a "large" dataframe (180 columns) and one-hot them so that I can find the correlation between the features and select the "best" features.

Here is my code:

```
# import labelencoder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# instantiate labelencoder object
le = LabelEncoder()

# apply le on categorical feature columns
df = df.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))
df.head(10)
```

When running this I get the following error:

`TypeError: ('argument must be a string or number', 'occurred at index LockTenor')`

So I head over to the LockTenor field and look at all the distinct values:

```
df.LockTenor.unique()
```

this results in the following:

`array([60.0, 45.0, 'z', 90.0, 75.0, 30.0], dtype=object)`

looks like all strings and numbers to me. Is the error caused because it's a float and not necessarily an INT?

Comment: Hi there. What happens if you change `df.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col))` to `df.apply(lambda col: LabelEncoder().fit_transform(col))`? I wonder if your encoder is getting confused with the subsequent `fit_transform` calls because it's not being re-initialised.

Answer (score 16):

You get this error because indeed you have a combination of floats *and* strings. Take a look at this example:

```
# Preliminaries
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

# Create DataFrames

# df1 has all floats
d1 = {'LockTenor':[60.0, 45.0, 15.0, 90.0, 75.0, 30.0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
print("DataFrame 1")
print(df1)

# df2 has a string in the mix
d2 = {'LockTenor':[60.0, 45.0, 'z', 90.0, 75.0, 30.0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
print("DataFrame 2")
print(df2)

# Create encoder
le = LabelEncoder()

# Encode first DataFrame 1 (where all values are floats)
df1 = df1.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col), axis=0, result_type='expand')
print("DataFrame 1 encoded")
print(df1)

# Encode first DataFrame 2 (where there is a combination of floats and strings)
df2 = df2.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col), axis=0, result_type='expand')
print("DataFrame 2 encoded")
print(df2)
```

If you run this code, you will see that `df1` is encoded with no problem, since all its values are floats. However, you will get the error that you are reporting for `df2`.

An easy fix, is to cast the column to a string. You can do this in the corresponding lambda function:

```
df2 = df2.apply(lambda col: le.fit_transform(col.astype(str)), axis=0, result_type='expand')
```

As an additional suggestion, I would recommend you take a look at your data and see if they are correct. For me, it is a bit weird having a mix of floats and strings in the same column.

Finally, I would just like to point out that [sci-kit's `LabelEncoder` performs a simple encoding of variables](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing_targets.html#label-encoding), it does *not* performe one-hot encoding. If you wish to do so, I recommend you take a look at [`OneHotEncoder`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Comment: thank you this worked! the z is my NAN replacement :)

Comment: Interesting choice. I would suggest that you use numpy's [`np.nan`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/misc.html) or pandas' [`pd.NA`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#missing-data-na) (from 1.0 on). This way, you can use more functions that easily handle missing values (such as [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna)

Comment: Hi, I have a similar problem. If you have time, can request your help with this related post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71193740/typeerror-encoders-require-their-input-to-be-uniformly-strings-or-numbers-got

Answer (score 5):

Try with this:

```
df[cat] = le.fit_transform(df[cat].astype(str))
```