# TypeError: argument must be a string or number

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm using the code below:

```py
cat_cols = ['MSZoning','Alley','LotShape','LandContour','Utilities','LotConfig','LandSlope','Neighborhood','Condition1','Condition2','BldgType','HouseStyle','RoofStyle','RoofMatl','Exterior1st','Exterior2nd','MasVnrType','ExterQual','ExterCond','Foundation','BsmtQual','BsmtCond','BsmtExposure','BsmtFinType1','BsmtFinType2','Heating','HeatingQC','CentralAir','Electrical','KitchenQual','Functional','FireplaceQu','GarageType','GarageFinish','GarageQual','GarageCond','PavedDrive','PoolQC','Fence','MiscFeature','SaleType','SaleCondition']

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()

for col in cat_cols:
    if col in dataset_train.columns:
        i = dataset_train.columns.get_loc(col)
        dataset_train.iloc[:,i] =le.fit_transform(dataset_train.iloc[:,i])
```

---

It gives an error as shown below:

> TypeError: argument must be a string or number

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: if error shows `"argument must be a string or number"` then check what you have in variables.

Comment: you could also use `dataset_train[col] = le.fit_transform(dataset_train[col])`

Comment: I can get this error if I have ie. `list` in cell - ie. `dataset_train = pd.DataFrame({'Alley':[['A','B','C']]})` - so in some column you have values which can't be encoded - you could at least use `print(col)` to see which column makes problem.

Comment: BTW: for every column you should create separated `LabelEncoder` - if you use the same `LabelEncoder` for two columns then you will remove old values and you could not use it to encode column back to original values.

Comment: yes @furas when I added the columns wherein a list, hence when I added the word list the error disappeared Thank you !!

Comment: It seems this question was better answered here: [SciKit-Learn Label Encoder resulting in error 'argument must be a string or number'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868256/scikit-learn-label-encoder-resulting-in-error-argument-must-be-a-string-or-numb)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to the problem

this is the code I wrote. (ps: luckily i have the house price prediction dataset with me :D")

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

path="....\house pricing"
filepath=os.path.join(path,"train.csv")

dataset_train=pd.read_csv(filepath)
dataset_train

cat_features=[x for x in dataset_train.columns if dataset_train[x].dtype=="object"]

le=LabelEncoder()

for col in cat_features:
    if col in dataset_train.columns:
        i = dataset_train.columns.get_loc(col)
        dataset_train.iloc[:,i] = dataset_train.apply(lambda i:le.fit_transform(i.astype(str)), axis=0, result_type='expand')
```

**Thus just you have to modify this:**

```
dataset_train.iloc[:,i] =le.fit_transform(dataset_train.iloc[:,i])
```

**with**

```
dataset_train.iloc[:,i] = dataset_train.apply(lambda i:le.fit_transform(dataset_train[i].astype(str)), axis=0, result_type='expand')
```

The above lamda function will convert each column and its data points(row wise **axis=0**) to "str" and then pass it through the "le" or LableEncoder function via the "fit_transform" to LabelEncode it.

Comment: `.astype(str)` did the trick for me, thanks.