# LabelEncoder -- TypeError: argument must be a string or number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
df=pd.read_csv("https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/831JKKEkW7kqd5M4evNva9LyB/insurance_grouped.csv")
le = LabelEncoder()#use this encoder to encod
df.BMI_group = le.fit_transform(df.BMI_group.values)
print(df.head())
```

---

Expected output - 
  age  sex     bmi  children  smoker  region      charges  BMI_group
0   19    0  27.900         0       1       3  16884.92400          2
1   18    1  33.770         1       0       2   1725.55230          1
2   28    1  33.000         3       0       2   4449.46200          1
3   33    1  22.705         0       0       1  21984.47061          0
4   32    1  28.880         0       0       1   3866.85520          2

---

Error message - 
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode)
    104         try:
--> 105             res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
    106         except TypeError:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
     58     if uniques is None:
---> 59         uniques = sorted(set(values))
     60         uniques = np.array(uniques, dtype=values.dtype)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      4 #df=pd.read_csv("https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/831JKKEkW7kqd5M4evNva9LyB/insurance_grouped.csv")
      5 le = LabelEncoder()#use this encoder to encod
----> 6 df.BMI_group = le.fit_transform(df.BMI_group.values)
      7 df.BMI_group

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in fit_transform(self, y)
    234         """
    235         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
--> 236         self.classes_, y = _encode(y, encode=True)
    237         return y
    238

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py in _encode(values, uniques, encode)
    105             res = _encode_python(values, uniques, encode)
    106         except TypeError:
--> 107             raise TypeError("argument must be a string or number")
    108         return res
    109     else:

TypeError: argument must be a string or number

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58868256/scikit-learn-label-encoder-resulting-in-error-argument-must-be-a-string-or-numb)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `np.nan` that are interpreted as floats, so cannot be compared to srting values. Here is updated code.

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
df=pd.read_csv("https://media-doselect.s3.amazonaws.com/generic/831JKKEkW7kqd5M4evNva9LyB/insurance_grouped.csv")
df["BMI_group"] = df["BMI_group"].replace(np.nan, 'none', regex=True)


le = LabelEncoder()#use this encoder to encod
df.BMI_group = le.fit_transform(df.BMI_group.values)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: No worries, mate!